# Perl | Archive::Tar | access denied after file extraction | preserve permissions

Tags: perl, permissions, cygwin, file-permissions, tar

I was having difficulty figuring out why I could not open files after they had been extracted from a tar file.  When i tried to open or read the contents of a file i had just extracted from a tar, i would receive an 'access denied' error message.  I was about to post the question on StackOverflow when I finally figured out what I was doing wrong.  Thought I'd post the question and answer for anyone who needs it in the future.  The easy solution would have just to use something besides Perl Tar, but ...

~~~PROBLEM~~~

You extract the contents of a tar file.  If you get access denied messages when trying to open or read a file you have just extracted from a tar file, it is probably because permissions were not preserved when tarring the files/directory.

~~~SOLUTION~~~

As stated in:

http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html#GLOBAL-VARIABLES

By default, Archive::Tar will try to chmod your files (mess with permissions).  To prevent this, you need to set the following global variable to '0':

$Archive::Tar::CHMOD = 0; # PRESERVE PERMISSIONS

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The below code shows how to use the global variable in perl code (additional comments/suggestions/critiques are welcome) ...

```
#folder structure:

# /cygdrive/c/00_backup_base  
#                |
#                |
#                +---- base
#                        |
#                        |
#                        +----00_TEST


#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;   
use warnings 'all';   
use Archive::Tar;   
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;

my $ACID='/cygdrive/c/00_backup_base'; 
my $myTarFile='base_tar.gz';
my $testDir="00_TEST";
my $base='base';

# ----- ZIP DIRECTORY ----
  my @inventory = (); #array, store list of director contents
  chdir $ACID or die "chdir failed on $ACID\n";
  find (sub { push @inventory, $File::Find::name }, "$base");

  #_Create a new tar object
  $Archive::Tar::CHMOD = 0; # PRESERVE PERMISSIONS!
  my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();

  $tar->add_files( @inventory );

  # Write compressed tar file
  print " Create Zip file \n";
  $tar->write( "$myTarFile"); 
  chdir "../..";

# ----- EXTRACT FILES -----
  chdir $ACID;
  copy("${archive}", "${testDir}/${archive}"); 
  chdir ${testDir};

  # Now extract:
  $Archive::Tar::CHMOD = 0; # PRESERVE PERMISSIONS!
  my $tar_b = Archive::Tar->new();   
  $tar_b->read( $myTarFile );   
  $tar_b->extract();
```

Answer (score 1):

answered above in initial post

additional comments/suggestions/critiques are welcome

~~~SOLUTION~~~

If you get access denied messages when trying to open or read a file you have just extracted from a tar file, it is probably because permissions were not preserved when tarring the files/directory.

As stated in:

http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html#GLOBAL-VARIABLES

By default, Archive::Tar will try to chmod your files (mess with permissions). To prevent this, you need to set the following global variable to '0':

$Archive::Tar::CHMOD = 0; # PRESERVE PERMISSIONS

Comment: please remove the answer from your question post

Comment: I think it's vice-versa. setting $Archive::Tar::CHMOD  to '0' will cause NOT PRESERVE PERMISSION